# Insert and Update Column using reference date column to update or insert columns

Tags: excel, vba, data-manipulation

I am currently in the process of automating my `VBA macro-enabled` file.

I have three `spreadsheets`,

The `datasheet` which is used to get the date column (This sheet will be updated every month and has the date column) it looks like this,

[image]

The date column is extracted from this column and used as a reference in the second `spreadsheet`,

[image]

Taking this extracted date as a reference, I want to update the master `spreadsheet` by updating if the month reference from the second image is already present else insert a new column and add rows to the inserted column like this,

[image]

If you need any more clarity, I am happy to provide it. Stuck for a long time and facing deadline pressure, any help will be much appreciated.

I have used this code so far, but it;s for the array and it's giving error as type mismatch

'''

```
Sub AddColumns_ClosedWB()
Dim v As Range
    Set v = Worksheets("Pivot_Sheet_1").Range("E3")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wb As Range
    Set wb = Worksheets("Main_Sheet_1").Range("D3:O3")
Dim x As Range
For x = 0 To v
If Cells(1, x + 1).value = v(x) Then GoTo nnext
If Cells(1, x + 1) <> "" Then
Cells(1, x + 1).EntireColumn.Insert
Cells(1, x + 1).value = v(x)
End If
If Cells(1, x + 1) = "" Then
Cells(1, x + 1).value = v(x)
End If
nnext:
Next
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).value = 0
End
wb.Save
wb.Close False

ActiveWorkbook.Save

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

'''

Here I want to update the INT values coming from the first sheet instead of a zero.

I am currently trying this and I am not able to select a single cell and use it in for and if loop to insert a new column when the column is not present in the list, like in the above picture, June and July are present so we just have to update the column, but Sep is not present so we have to insert a new column, next time september comes in, the column will just be updated.

'''

```
Sub MapCells()

    Dim month As Range
    month = Worksheets("Pivot_Sheet_1").Range("E3").Select
    Dim all As Range
    all = Worksheets("Main_Sheet_1").Range("D3:O3").Select
    Dim lastHCell As Range
    
    For Each month In all
        Dim k: k = Application.Match(month, header, 0)
        If IsError(k) And month <> vbNullString Then _
            lastHCell.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=True:
                Set lastHCell = lastHCell.Offset(0, 1): lastHCell.Value2 = month
            
    Next month
    

End Sub
```

'''

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please make an attempt on your own first, and then come here when you run into problems.